# debugging workflows and/or activities in VSCode or similar

Tags: python, temporal-workflow

If we have code for Temporal workflows/activities and want to step through the code line-by-line in a debugger, for example with VSCode, is there any reasonably easy way of doing that?

I saw that there is a Temporal VSCode extension, but it seems to only be written for TypeScript.

I've tried pulling some of my workflow code out of the workflow class to run directly. However it's not so straightforward because there may be additional `workflow.*` calls which won't work at all if you aren't in the event loop.

Comment: Which language are you using exactly? You can simply add the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Also, are you trying to debug a Workflow while it is executing for the very first time, or are you replaying it, using history? You mention the Temporal VSCode extension... That extension only allows debugging a past Workflow Execution, ie. by replaying its history. You can do pretty much the same in all officially supported SDKs by using the replayer API and regular breakpoints.

Comment: I'm using Python. I don't think this is a pure Python question though - the entry point is into a specific method (the run method) which complicates things, plus typically you will have other methods to launch activities which will cause errors when you get to them outside of a Temporal context. In any case I was trying to debug a workflow while it's executing for the first time, so I guess the extension doesn't help.

Comment: It's definitely not a pure Python question, but Temporal SDKs for different languages works differently enough for this information to still be pertinent.

Comment: Ok! I added the tag :)

Comment: Do you have any issues starting the Python worker process with the VS Code debugger and setting a breakpoint as you would with any other Python code? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Comment: Well, you have to create an additional script to invoke the Workflow, which I guess is standard. The bigger issue is that when you get to functions like `await workflow.execute_activity(my_activity, my_activity_input)` or `workflow.logger.info`, it will break if you're just running that from within VSCode. My workaround is to manually change the first statement to just `await my_activity(my_activity_input)` and the second to just a `print` statement, but it would be nice to not have to change the code to debug it.